# Is my 1D signal using CNN & RNN regression reasonable?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, time-series, signal-processing

I want to know if my impact-echo signals are proper with CNN or RNN regression model.

I got some simulated signal, as following shows.[image: figure]

In previous research, people mostly consider frequency or even time-frequency analysis. For deeper crack the signal response lower frequency [image: here].

Singal input are their 1D signal, and want output present their depths. But my train simulated crack are all create integer (e.g. 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26), so I'm wondering if these signals in time domain using CNN [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dayRZ.jpg) or RNN [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zahzb.jpg) model do regression task is reasonable. (Is my RNN model wrong or BIG concept misleading)

And I hope the model can learn (e.g. train 10cm and 12cm depth crack signal, when the model input is a 11cm signal it can be predict as 11).

Also if it is reasonable, which paper should I read or some paper related to enhance knowledge.

If the question is not clearly describe, please told me (I'm not native in English). Thank you guys.

Comment: I see you have many points (X axis) in each depth crack. Do you need to put entire signal to neural network or could you cut to small period like 1024 points and feed to neural network?

Comment: @CloudCho Oh you are right!
In frequency domain analysis, we need to take a longer time to achieve higher frequency resolution. However, on the flip side, a longer time duration can make the signal more susceptible to interference from boundaries or other reflections. This is  one of the advantages that I think 1D signals can get good performance. Currently, I'm using 448 data points (μs) for each input signal.
I'm wondering what I'm doing (make CNN or RNN doing these regression) is reasonable.

Comment: 448 point in X axis would be doable in CNN. By the way, how human detect the depth of crack visually from the graph?

Comment: On-site, I think people use FFT to check frequency peak (at high frequency). And decide if  there have a crack under impact point.

Comment: Then you may consider to use FFT plot instead of time series as your dataset.